# How do I see what a file looks like after preprocessing?

Tags: c++, debugging, c-preprocessor

How can I check the results of preprocessing?  For example, say I have the following code:

```
#define CONCATENATE(X, Y) X ## Y
#define STRING_1 First
#define STRING_2 Second
#define STRING_3 CONCATENATE(STRING_1, STRING_2)
```

Is there a way to make sure `STRING_3` will be expanded to `FirstSecond` later in the program?

Comment: Depend what compiler you are working with.

Comment: You mean, apart from (1) staring at it until it gives up or (2) running the preprocessor over it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each compiler should provide a switch to keep the preprocessed code

- gcc: `-E`
- MS Visual Studio: `Keep preprocessed files` in the settings or `/P` switch

For other compilers I bet you'll find a suitable switch in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing to do is run the C++ file under `g++ -E <file> -o <file>.out` and then check the result that way.

I assume you mean check it as in debug - obviously you can't check it at runtime as the preprocessor information won't exist.